# Place arcs and random values in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, rotating, arc, random

I am making a figure representing a magnetic-core memory. First, I have difficulty in positioning the arcs that represent the electromagnetic currents. I made two tkzfigures and put the second one over the first, but the effect was not good.

Second, I would like the magnetization directions of the  to be random, that is, some clockwise (rotate = 135) and others counterclockw (rotate = -135).

```
\newcommand{\DrawCore}[2]{
    \node [draw, cylinder, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=white, shape aspect=4, rotate=135, minimum width=2cm, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at 
    (#1*3+0,#2*3+0){};
    \node [draw, ellipse, minimum width=1.4cm, rotate=-135, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at (3*#1-0.4,3*#2+0.35){};
    \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1*3-1.9,#2*3+0.4) -- (#1*3-0.255,#2*3+0.4);
    \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1*3+0.65,#2*3+0.4) -- (#1*3+1.2,#2*3+0.4);
    
    \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1*3-0.4,#2*3+1.4) -- (#1*3-0.4,#2*3+0.1);
    \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1*3-0.4,#2*3-0.65) -- (#1*3-0.4,#2*3-1.6);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0, ..., 7}{
    \foreach \y [count = \yi] in {0, ..., 7}{
        \draw [-latex, thick, rotate=135] ({-2.2*\xi+2.2*(\yi)}, {+2.2*\xi+2.2*(\yi)}) arc [start angle=190, end angle=-160, x radius=0.8cm, y radius=1.4cm];
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,scale=0.5, transform shape]
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0, ..., 7}{
    \foreach \y [count = \yi] in {0, ..., 7}{
    \DrawCore{\xi}{\yi};
    }
}
```

This is the desired result:
[image: magnetic-core memory]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code. Then give a freehand diagram of the desired result.

Comment: Hi AndréC! Thank you. I think if you have some idea about how to provide random clockwise and counterclockw rotation, you can work over LaTeXdraw-com.s code, that's much better than my code.

Comment: That's not the problem, the custom is to give an MWE in the questions, read: [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Answer (score 4):

Here is my attempt for the first part of your request:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\DrawCore}[2]{
\begin{scope}[rotate around={135:(#1,#2)}]
\node [draw, cylinder, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=white, shape aspect=4, rotate=0, minimum width=2cm, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at 
    (#1,#2){};
 \node [draw, ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1.4cm, rotate=0, line width=0.5mm] (c2) at (c1.top-|c1.before top){};
    \draw[-latex,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
\end{scope}

\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-1.9,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.255,#2+0.4);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1+0.65,#2+0.4) -- (#1+1.2,#2+0.4);
    
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+1.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+0.1);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2-0.65) -- (#1-0.4,#2-1.6);

  
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0,3,...,12}{
    \foreach \y [count = \yi] in {0,3,...,12}{
    \DrawCore{\x}{\y};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

I've slightly modified your code and used nodes anchors (c1 and c2).

**Update:**
To draw arrows with different directions, you can check at each case if the position is odd or even using:

```
\ifodd <integer> <TeX code 1> [\else <TeX code 2>] \fi
```

Here is the corresponding code in this case:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\DrawCore}[3]{

\begin{scope}[rotate around={135:(#1,#2)}]
\node [draw, cylinder, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=white, shape aspect=4, minimum width=2cm, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at 
    (#1,#2){};
 \node [draw, ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1.4cm, rotate=0, line width=0.5mm] (c2) at (c1.top-|c1.before top){};
 
% Odd or even: choose arrow direction
\ifodd #3 \draw[-latex,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255); 
[\else
\draw[latex-,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);]\fi
\end{scope}

\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-1.9,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.255,#2+0.4);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1+0.65,#2+0.4) -- (#1+1.2,#2+0.4);
    
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+1.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+0.1);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2-0.65) -- (#1-0.4,#2-1.6);

}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0,3,...,12}{
    \foreach \y [count = \yi,evaluate=\y as \z using int( \xi+\yi )] in {0,3,...,12}{
    \DrawCore{\x}{\y}{\z};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image]

If you would like to rotate the shape, here is the corresponding code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\DrawCore}[3]{

\ifodd #3 
\begin{scope}[rotate around={135:(#1,#2)}]
\node [draw, cylinder, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=white, shape aspect=4, minimum width=2cm, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at 
    (#1,#2){};
 \node [draw, ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1.4cm, rotate=0, line width=0.5mm] (c2) at (c1.top-|c1.before top){};
 
\draw[-latex,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
\end{scope}

\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-1.9,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.255,#2+0.4);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1+0.65,#2+0.4) -- (#1+1.2,#2+0.4);
    
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+1.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+0.1);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2-0.65) -- (#1-0.4,#2-1.6);

[\else 

\begin{scope}[yshift=0.5cm]
\begin{scope}[rotate around={-135:(#1,#2)}]
\node [draw, cylinder, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=white, shape aspect=4, minimum width=2cm, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at 
    (#1,#2){};
 \node [draw, ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1.4cm, rotate=0, line width=0.5mm] (c2) at (c1.top-|c1.before top){};
 
\draw[latex-,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
\end{scope}
\end{scope}

\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-1.9,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+0.4);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1+0.5,#2+0.4) -- (#1+1.2,#2+0.4);
    
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+1.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+1.2);
\draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2-1.6);
]\fi
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0,3,...,12}{
    \foreach \y [count = \yi,evaluate=\y as \z using int( \xi+\yi )] in {0,3,...,12}{
    \DrawCore{\x}{\y}{\z};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:
[image]

Comment: Very very good and I have appreciated your work.

Comment: Many thanks Sebastiano, I am happy that you liked it :)

Comment: Thank you! It was really good!

Comment: Thanks Cristian, check the modified version!

Comment: Your web site http://latexdraw.com seems to be down or lost. Would you like that I host it for you? (free, of cause) As it's about TikZ, we could use the non-used http://tikz.net address, which I just forwarded to the github project.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz It was a mistake from the customer service and my website was deleted by changing the hosting plan :'(. I've lost all data, it remains only pages from archive org :D. I have to start from scratch and tikz.net is a great domain name.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Commercial domain grabbers run automated domain name backorders and may have taken it that way once it became available after the accidental deletion. I can help restoring it, just send me an email and we can get started somehow.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeXdraw-com, the result of your code is really pretty beautiful. The rotation of the cores also improved a lot and made the illustration closer to the physical implementation of magnetic core memories. I made a small change over your code so that the direction of the magnetic flow of a core is determined randomly and not according to their position, since the direction indicates whether the core's content is 1 or 0. Thanks again!

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[first=0, last=1, quiet]{lcg} % rand


\begin{document}
   
   \newcommand{\DrawCore}[3]{
   
       \ifodd #3 
       \begin{scope}[rotate around={135:(#1,#2)}]
           \node [draw, cylinder, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=white, shape aspect=4, minimum width=2cm, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at 
           (#1,#2){};
           \node [draw, ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1.4cm, rotate=0, line width=0.5mm] (c2) at (c1.top-|c1.before top){};
           \rand\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{rand}}{1}}{
               \draw[-latex,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
           }{
               \draw[latex-,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
           }
           %\draw[-latex,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
       \end{scope}
       
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-1.9,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.255,#2+0.4);
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1+0.65,#2+0.4) -- (#1+1.2,#2+0.4);
       
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+1.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+0.1);
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2-0.65) -- (#1-0.4,#2-1.6);
       
       [\else 
       
       \begin{scope}[yshift=0.5cm]
           \begin{scope}[rotate around={-135:(#1,#2)}]
               \node [draw, cylinder, cylinder uses custom fill, cylinder body fill=white, shape aspect=4, minimum width=2cm, line width=0.5mm] (c1) at 
               (#1,#2){};
               \node [draw, ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=1.4cm, rotate=0, line width=0.5mm] (c2) at (c1.top-|c1.before top){};
               \rand\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{rand}}{1}}{
                   \draw[-latex,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
               }{
                   \draw[latex-,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
               }
               %\draw[latex-,red] (c1.85|-c1.105) to[bend right=25] (c1.275|-c1.255);
           \end{scope}
       \end{scope}
       
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-1.9,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+0.4);
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1+0.5,#2+0.4) -- (#1+1.2,#2+0.4);
       
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+1.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2+1.2);
       \draw [line width=0.5mm] (#1-0.4,#2+0.4) -- (#1-0.4,#2-1.6);
       ]\fi
   }
   
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
   \foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0,3,...,12}{
       \foreach \y [count = \yi,evaluate=\y as \z using int( \xi+\yi )] in {0,3,...,12}{
           \DrawCore{\x}{\y}{\z};
       }
   }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! now we have a complete answer to your question :)